# Outdoors vs in the outdoors

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar

If somebody likes sleeping in the open, which of the following sentences is correct? And if both are correct, what is the difference (if any) between them?

> He likes sleeping *outdoors*.
>
> He likes sleeping *in the outdoors*.

And do they mean the same as **in the open**?

Comment: ***Outdoors*** is an adverb. If something happens outdoors, it does not happen inside a building.
He spent a lot of his time outdoors.
School classes were held outdoors.
When someone goes out of a building, you don't usually say that they go 'outdoors'. You say that they go outside.http://www.thefreedictionary.com/outdoor :

Comment: @Josh61 I know, but what sentence is correct and is there difference between **to sleep outdoors** and **to sleep in the outdoors**? And do they have the same meaning as **in the open**?

Comment: Both are correct.  "Sleeping outdoors" would be more idiomatic in the US, though sometimes "in the outdoors" is used as a sort of emphasis.  And the expression does mean "in the open", though there are subtle differences in tone and secondary implications (that I can't quite get my hands on at present).

Comment: The MacMillan Dict.  actually cites the expression *in the outdoors* : https://books.google.it/books?id=lTK4u2tAkhQC&pg=PT566&dq=%22walk+in+the+outdoors%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=MgxjVYXLJ6XSyAP0sYF4&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22walk%20in%20the%20outdoors%22&f=false

Comment: _In the outdoors_ sounds very odd. How can one be **in** an exterior?

Comment: @DogLover - it sounds odds to me too, but the expression is actually  used: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+outdoors&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20outdoors%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @DogLover and josh61 if you can be **in** the countryside, you can be *in* the outdoors. The expression [**in the great outdoors**](https://www.google.it/search?q=in+the+great+outdoors&oq=in+the+great+outdoors&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22in+the+great+outdoors%22&tbm=bks) is more common, and idiomatic, I believe.

Comment: @Josh61 the expression is common. "You can stay *in* the sunshine", but you're still outside, "you live *in* a city", "in a country", etc.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, I do actually say _in the great outdoors_.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I know that the expression is commonly used, but I've always thought it was an improper usage of an adverb. Outdoors as a noun, actually, in not present in many dictionaries. ODO cites it just in the set phrase *great outdoors*.         http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/it/definizione/inglese/outdoors

Comment: @Mari-LouA - btw, I have never heard *in the sunshine* before..is that common too? :))

Answer (score 3):

If you say that someone "sleeps *outdoors*," the most common inference would be that they are homeless - or perhaps they can't abide the air-conditioning. It usually brings to mind a picture of someone in a setting where there are indoor places to sleep. (A city, or a residential neighborhood.)

If you say "sleeps in *the outdoors,* one assumes that there is a lack of permanent, man-made shelter nearby. "*The outdoors*" is another way of saying "the wilderness" or "open country". (US)

Comment: Actually, it would not be unusual for someone to "sleep outdoors" by sleeping on a screened porch, say, in the summer.